# Proof of a self-adjoint linear transformation

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, determinant, trace, self-adjoint-operators

Let V be a subset of ${R^3}$ and be a two-dimensional subspace. Let $W: V\rightarrow V$ be a self-adjoint linear transformation. Define K=det(W) and H=$(1/2)$trace(W).

Prove that $K \leq H^2$

What I have so far:
Since W is self-adjoint, W is represented by a matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&\lambda_2  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & \lambda_3
\end{bmatrix}$

With eigenvalues along the diagonal.

$K=det(W)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3$ $\   $$H^2=1/4(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)^2$

Any direction on how to go about solving this proof is appreciated

Comment: Hint: Think in terms of the eigenvalues.

Comment: $V$ is two dimensional so how can your 3 vectors be a basis?

Comment: Your matrix is $3x3$ so how can it represent $W$ wrt to your (now) basis of $2$ vectors? I think you may be confusing the fact that the vectors are three tuples but when you consider the matrix of $W$ it is with respect to the $coefficients$ of your arbitrary vector in $V$ written as a linear combination of your basis vectors (in $V$).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$1).\ $The determinant, trace, eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a square matrix are invariant under change of basis.

$2).\ $ Every self-adjoint linear transformation on a finite- dimensional inner product space has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

$3).\ $ the eigenvalues of a self-adjoint operator are real.

$4).\ $ for any two real numbers $a,b,\ ab\le \frac{1}{2}(a+b)^2$

Comment: Is my calculation for H^2 correct where I get 1/4*(traceW)^2. The 1/4 doesn't fit

Comment: I can't really follow your proof. Have you tried using the hints in my answer?